# Angularjs debounce is clearing my radio input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, debouncing

I have the following radio button group:

```
<input type="radio" name="GROUP" ng-model="data1" id="for1" value="value" ng-change="formSubmit()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 3000}">
<input type="radio" name="GROUP" ng-model="data2" id="for2" value="value" ng-change="formSubmit()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 3000}">
```

As you can see, on `ng-click`, I have it run a particular function but also have a `debounce` to only occur with a 3 second timeout.

When I have `ng-model-options="{debounce: 3000}"` present, very often, my radio groups will uncheck-  meaning no input's in the group will be checked.

When I remove the debounce, this problem doesn't occur.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle to demonstrate please.

Comment: @rikAtee http://plnkr.co/edit/0OovzU9mMDtbgLfYWYYc

Comment: I tried this: http://embed.plnkr.co/xJlhU2fpLLtxdQFlBMhH   When I try switching from one option to the other I seem to get both radio buttons selected until the debounce occurs, and then the switch (any clicks during the debounce period are ignored.)  Which seems both technically correct and a very poor user experience; perhaps the simplest answer here is "don't debounce single-click form elements, because there's no good to do that"?

Comment: @danielbeck I'd like to call a function when an input is edited, but with a timeout of 3 seconds. I can't seem to figure out any other way to do this than a debounce. Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment thread above, and assuming you want to keep the first click and ignore subsequent ones within the 3 second delay, I'd suggest:

`<input type="radio" ng-change="doItLater();" value="X">`

(meanwhile, in a directive:

```
scope.doItLater = function() {
    if (scope.timeoutwatcher !== undefined) {return;}
    scope.timeoutwatcher = $timeout(function() {
        // do it
        delete scope.timeoutwatcher;
    },3000);
}
```

Or if you're looking to let later clicks within the timeout period  override earlier ones,

```
scope.doItLater = function() {
    $timeout.cancel(scope.timeoutwatcher);
    scope.timeoutwatcher = $timeout(function() {
        // do it
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: for the second one I get, `Error: Can't find variable: $timeout`

Comment: you need to inject $timeout as a dependency.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('example', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.$watch('user.gender', $scope.callback);
        $scope.callback = function() {
            alert($scope.user);
        }
    }]);
```

and in the html so something like

```
  <form ng-app="app" ng-controller="example">
    <input name="jim" type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" ng-model-options="{debounce: 3000}" />male
    <input name="jim" type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" ng-model-options="{debounce: 3000}" />female
    <br />
  <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
```